# Database Relationship with Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

i am having trouble inserting data into my database according to my database structure. I have 3 tables. `Company table` `Users table` `branches table`.

Now this is how i made the relationship between these tables.

**Company table and Users table have one to many relationship**

**Company table and Branches table have one to many relationship**

**Branches table and Users table have one to many relationsip**

This is how my model looks like

**PS**: I am only a beginner with database and laravel

**Company Model**

```
public function branches()
  {
      return $this->hasMany('App\Branch');
  }

  public function users()
  {
      return $this->hasMany('App\User');
  }
```

**User Model**

```
 public function company()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Company')
        ->withTimestamps();
    }

     public function branches()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Branch')
        ->withTimestamps();
    }
```

**Branch Model**

```
public function company()
    {
     return $this->belongsTo('App\Company');

    }

    public function users()
  {
      return $this->hasMany('App\User');
  }
```

Now, when a user registers, only  the company table is filled with it details but the user table and branch table is not filled and i get the error

```
"SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'company_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `branches` (`name`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Virginia, 2017-10-14 03:19:38, 2017-10-14 03:19:38)) ◀"
```

This is how i save the data in the RegisterController

**RegisterController**

```
protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'phone' => $data['phone'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),

            "company_id" => Company::create(
                [
                    "name" => $data['rname'],
                    "email" => $data['remail'],
                    "phone" => $data['rphone'],
                    "address" => $data['raddress']           

                ]
           )->id,

            "branch_id" => Branch::create (
                   [
                       "name" => $data['rbranch']
                   ]
               )->id   


        ]);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try this may be its help for you:

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $company =  Company::create(
            [
                "name" => $data['rname'],
                "email" => $data['remail'],
                "phone" => $data['rphone'],
                "address" => $data['raddress']           

            ]);
```

**Updated Answer**

```
    $branch = Branch::create (
               [
                   "name" => $data['rbranch'],
                   "company_id" => $company->id
               ]
           );

    if(isset($company->id) && isset($branch->id)){
      return User::create([
          'name' => $data['name'],
          'email' => $data['email'],
          'phone' => $data['phone'],
          'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),

          "company_id" => $company->id,

          "branch_id" => $branch->id   


      ]);
    } else{
        return redirect()->back()->withFlashDanger("company or branch no successfully insterted");

    }

}
```

Comment: branch also has a foriegn key `company_id`. Is that also going to set after the company is created?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create nullable foreign keys...

In your migration, use the ->nullable() function...

```
$table->integer('company_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
```

This will let you not include a company_id initially, the value will be null... without the nullable() the database will not allow null values...

Hope this helps.

Comment: That is exactly what i have done in my migrations. Now, users table has branch_id which i expect to be filled with the id of the branch that would be created. Also, the company_id of the company created should also reflect in the branch table

Comment: @XamarinLearner Did you edit your migration `after` you had switched this? if so, you may need to do a migrate refresh or manually change your database structure. This is purely a db structure problem.